# Making Player Fall On Only Platforms

Tags: java, game-physics

I am trying to create a 2D platformer, and I am about to try and implement jumping. However, I am sort of lost on how to make the player only fall on to platforms.

I was thinking create a new class called Platform, and then create an ArrayList of all the coordinates of all of the platforms in the game.

I then create a while loop, and whenever the player jumps, when he is falling, it continues falling unless he is standing on a platform?

Something like:

```
while(// This is where you check if the player's y coordinate is above all of the platforms in the game, so WHILE you are above all of the platforms, continue falling.){

      playery--;
      repaint();
      // Some kind of wait here
}
```

Am I taking the correct approach here?
Am I over complicating it? Is there an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: What you are thinking is definitely one way to go about it. There are many others.

Comment: @nhouser9 Updated main post for this question, but am I taking the easiest approach? Or am I over complicating this.

Comment: What happens to a player when he walks off a platform (i.e. not jumping?)
It should be part of your normal game loop (whether jumping or not). After every update cycle, you process input, calculate the new position, update the player to the new position, and repaint. Part of the calculation should include if the player is on a floor. Doing that depends on what sort of algorithm you're wanting to check. That may be going through arrays, or a box collision, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have an update() and a render()- method in your playerobject. For easy gravity you can update your players y-position with every update call, e.g. posY+=5. For advanced gravity you have a y-velocity with which you update the y-position every update. This y-velocity changes for smoother movement.

You should have a controller-class that holds every entity in your game in some collection. In my game this class is called EntityManager and it holds every Entity in LinkedLists. I would recommend to have several collections for different entity-types. In this case you could have BlockEntities which represent square blocks which make your platforms.

Now the most important concept. Every entity has a method which returns a Rectangle Object as a hitbox.
Here is an example of a game i made:

```
 public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle( x, y, width, height);
    }
```

x, y, width and height are properties of the entity.

Additionally your player needs a hitbox that is located at the bottom of your player. For example if the players size would be 32x32 pixels:

```
 public Rectangle getBottomBounds() {
    return new Rectangle( x, y+30, width, 2);
}
```

Now comes the collision control:
In your player you need a field like this:

```
    protected LinkedList<Block> blocks = null;
```

In your player you implement this method:

```
public void checkBottomCollision() {
    blocks = game.getEntityManager().getBlocks();
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) { 
        Block tempBlock = blocks.get(i);
            if(this.getBottomBounds().intersects(tempBlock.getBounds())){
                this.y = tempBlock.getY() + this.height;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

game.getEntityManager() gets the ControllerClass which holds all the entities in my game. The method getBlocks() returns a LinkedList with all the blocks.
You check if the player's collision for every block. If the bottom-hitbox collides you update the position so your player stands on the block.
You call this method in your update-method AFTER you update the y-position.

Have fun with it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the informational answer! Will definitely do this! :)